# How do I get Discord member, mentioned in the message and grant him a role?

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

That's the code that I came up with

```cs
var roleMuted = ctx.Guild.GetRole(role id);
var userId = ctx.Message.MentionedUsers.First().Id;
DiscordMember member = ctx.Guild.GetMemberAsync(user); //exception here
await member.GrantRoleAsync(roleMuted);
```

It gives me an exception

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type `"System.Threading.Tasks.Task< DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMember>"` to `"DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMember"`

As you can see here - my intention in that line is to create a variable of class `DiscordMember` and set it to the `DiscordMember` that was returned by  `ctx.Guild.GetMemberAsync()`, but for some reason, `Visual Studio` tells me that `DiscordMember`, that was returned by `GetMemberAsync()` is not the same as `DiscordMember` I'm trying to create, to later use for `.GrantRoleAsync()`, which confuses me a lot.

edit1**
And I have to add that if I replace `DiscordMember` with `var` for the line to be

`var member = ctx.Guild.GetMemberAsync(user);`
then instead of giving me an exception, about failed converting, I simply cannot call `.GrantRoleAsync()` method for the `member` variable (exception CS1061)

Comment: Please don't put tags in your question titles. There's a perfectly adequate tagging system that you're already using for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`GetMemberAsync` is an asynchronous method, you need to await it by putting the `await` keyword before it like you've done below with `GrantRoleAsync`. This will then return `DiscordMember` instead of `Task<DiscordMember>`.

As for your edit. Your type is now `Task<DiscordMember>` which means you wont get the methods for `DiscordMember` and instead get the methods for `Task<T>`